# слот при закрытии QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

Какой слот используется для закрытия `QWidget`? 
`Destroyed()` и `Destroyed(QObject*)` не подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать close()

Answer (score 2):

`destroyed` - это сигнал вызываемый после разрушения виджета. Он не удаляет виджет, а вызывается после удаления автоматически. Если вам нужен именно слот - вы можете воспользоваться `deleteLater()`, наследованный от `QObject` и выполняющей безопасное удаление объекта, либо функцией `close()`(эта функция не слот);